# Help with simplifying a basic algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just recently started taking math classes again at my uni (declared a math and computer science joint major) after not having taken serious math courses for about two years, since the end of high school. In order to refresh myself, I am taking a diagnostics test at the beginning of my textbook (James Stewart's Calculus). I am stuck on this one algebraic expression that I'm supposed to simplify:

$$\left(\frac{3x^{3/2}y^3}{x^2y^{-1/2}}\right)^{-2}$$

If anyone could please refresh my memory in how to simplify problems like these, I would be forever grateful. I'm a little scared to go to my professor because I don't want him to judge me for being a little behind.

Anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Negative powers are reciprocals so $x^{-a}=\frac{1}{x^a}$

Fractional powers are roots so $x^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x}$

So your messy expression can be tidied bit by bit:

$\left(\frac{3x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^3}{x^2y^{-\frac{1}{2}}}  \right)^{-2}$

is

$\left(\frac{x^2y^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{3x^{\frac{3}{2}}y^3}  \right)^{2}$

cancelling the $x$ terms

$\left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{3y^3}  \right)^{2}$

cancelling the $y$ terms

$\left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{3y^{\frac{7}{2}}}  \right)^{2}$

squaring

$\frac{x}{9y^7} $

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you taking the time to answer.